# Phonegap Maps with iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, cordova, apple-maps

So I have basically given up.  I have tried my best to search all possible ways to have a link open up map application in an app but I seem to fail.

Here's the situation: I want a particular link to open up in Android and iOS. Assuming some users probably don't have Google Maps installed on their Apple devices, I was wondering there can be an option to select any particular app they'd like.

My troubleshooting so far: I noticed geo: works in iOS and maps: works in Android but can't seem to have them both work on the different platforms.

I am pretty new to Phonegap and still learning.  Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your best option will be to go with "launch navigator". You should modify the functions and write conditions (to check the platform).It is the best option

Here is the link 
https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator

Comment: I am really having a hard time to implement this.  I downloaded the plugin but can't seem to make it work. I tried installing the example on my phone and it wouldn't work.  I've spent over 3 hours trying to make this work and I simply can't get it to work.

Here's how I installed the plugin: added plugin to config.xml file then copied the files from the www to my app directory where the index.html exists and added the src folder.  Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Are you using Cordova CLI ? using a terminal ..?

Comment: I am using Phonegap Build

Comment: Alright, so I stated Launch Navigator on a brand new app and it seems to work in iOS but does not work in Android.  What can I be possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Check if your mobile has google map installed in it! if yes then:
`launchnavigator.navigate(toAdress,fromAddress,null,null);`
Also make sure you have installed the plugin for android